# Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function error when calling mapping getter

Tags: mapping, getter, solidity

Having a mapping such as:

`mapping(address => uint[]) public myMapping`

creates automatically a getter. However when I call that getter like this: `myMapping(anAddress)` I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The created getter is `myMapping(anAddress, anIndex)` instead of `myMapping(anAddress)`. So there is no way to get all the array at once. Instead, caller should provide an index as a second argument to get the element at the provided index.

Example:

Assuming the uint array has four elements for `anAddress`, 2, 3, 5, 7, respectively:

`myMapping(anAddress, 2)` returns 5. And `myMapping(anAddress, 3)` returns 7.